# How to get max salary in each dept from 2 tables - sql?

Tags: sql, max, inner-join

I have 2 tables , department and employee. I need to get employee's name with max salary in each dept.

```
create table Dep(name_dep char, id_dep int);

insert into Dep values("econ", 1);
insert into Dep values("credit", 2);
insert into Dep values("energy", 3);
insert into Dep values("retail", 4);
insert into Dep values("manufactury", 5);

create table Emp(id_emp int, id_dep int, age int, person_name char, salary int );
insert into Emp values(1, 1, 23, 'john', 200);
insert into Emp values(3, 2, 3, 'dalbai', 100);
insert into Emp values(6, 3, 53, 'borat', 300);
insert into Emp values(7, 1, 63, 'erjan', 1600);
insert into Emp values(9, 2, 73, 'sergey', 1000);
insert into Emp values(8, 5, 83, 'lucy', 20);
insert into Emp values(90, 4, 93, 'mike', 1200);
```

How to query employee name with max salary in each dept?
My query:

```
SELECT person_name, name_dep
FROM Emp e
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT name_dep, MAX(salary) AS max_salary
    FROM Dep d
    GROUP BY id_dep
) d
    ON e.id_dep = d.id_dep
```

Comment: What's wrong with your query? Did you miss to add `max_salary` to the columns in the `SELECT` statement?

Comment: @Sami, i dont know, i m confused about the whole query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join the tables and the query that returns the max salary for each department:

```
select
  d.name_dep, e.person_name, t.salary
from Dep d inner join (
  select id_dep, max(salary) salary
  from Emp
  group by id_dep
) t on t.id_dep = d.id_dep
inner join Emp e on e.id_dep = t.id_dep and e.salary = t.salary
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d9DhoFVUTEPr4fa4tK41eH/1).
Results:

```
| name_dep    | person_name | salary |
| ----------- | ----------- | ------ |
| energy      | borat       | 300    |
| econ        | erjan       | 1600   |
| credit      | sergey      | 1000   |
| manufactury | lucy        | 20     |
| retail      | mike        | 1200   |
```

Answer (score 2):

Though I have corrected the Gordon's answer, But if you strictly need an ANCI approach, You can use below query -

```
SELECT e.person_name, d.name_dep, d.max_salary
FROM Emp e
INNER JOIN Dep d ON e.id_dep = d.id_dep
INNER JOIN (SELECT id_dep, MAX(salary) AS max_salary
            FROM Emp
            GROUP BY id_dep) d ON e.id_dep = d.id_dep
                               AND e.salary = d.max_salary
```

Basically you was using name_dep instead of id_dep which i have corrected.

Comment: This does not work. There is no column salary in the table Dep.

Comment: Also there is no column name_dep in the table Emp. Who upvoted this answer?

Comment: @forpas, Corrected the answer. Let me know if there are any other issues.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai yes the issue is that your answer is a copy of my answer.

Comment: Hmm, You would never believe it, but first I have updated my answer only then I seen your answer an realised that you have already answered it.

Comment: It's true I would never believe it, since you posted a wrong answer and only after my comments you edited.

Answer (score 0):

I have a table wich works pretty much the same way as your table, in that table I use a correlated subquery

```
select * from emp inner join dept on emp.deptno = dept.deptno where 
(emp.deptno, sal) in 
(select deptno, max(sal) from emp where deptno = emp.deptno 
group by emp.deptno);
```

the correlated query fetch the higher salary and department grouping by department, then, the outer query uses the results as conditions to extract information from the tables, I hove It helps

Answer (score -1):

Use window functions.  For one person, use `row_number()`:

```
SELECT person_name, name_dep
FROM (SELECT e.person_name, d.name_dep,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e.id_dep ORDER BY e.salary DESC) as seqnum
      FROM Emp e INNER JOIN
           Dep d
           ON e.id_dep = d.id_dep
     ) ed
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

If you want all duplicates in the case of ties, then use `RANK()`.

Comment: thx u, and how can i simplify it without using seqnum? and order by? just basic inner join

Comment: there is no max(salary) i need to use it

Comment: what is c.salary? c is not declared before

Comment: @ERJAN, c.salary is actually e.salary. I have edited that now. There no need to use max function as Window function ROW_NUMBER will do that on behalf of max(salary).

Comment: @GordonLinoff, You are always more than welcome. Please do share some SQL techniques (specifically ORACLE) with me if you can.